# [ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]COUNT field incorrect

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc

```
$q = 'INSERT INTO MyTable(proddesc, qnty, PriceH, PriceA, PriceL) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)';
$sth = odbc_prepare($dbConn, $q);
$success = odbc_execute($sth, array(my 5 variables that are not null));
```

It gives me the above error - `[ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] COUNT field incorrect`. I know that the query is correct because I ran it in Access and it was fine. I think I may be using the prepare/execute statements incorrectly.

Comment: Not really. The syntax looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this now and the solution I did to fix it is to quote the variables properly.

Try printing your $q and you will see if it needs to be quoted.

You can try these too:

- INSERT INTO `TABLE` -- quote db and table names using (**`**) "grave accent" character
- VALUES( 'Fed''s' ) -- quote the apostrophes