# RODBC with ms-access error 07002 17 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]COUNT field incorrect

Tags: r, ms-access, rodbc

### Problem:

I have a small database, for which MS Access works well. Using the `RODBC` package, I use `sqlSave` to create a new table with the `data.frame` in question. I tried to use `sqlSave` with `append=TRUE` to add the records directly to the table, but get a generic error that I can't append to that table, and I can't figure out why that's the case. So, I've built an `INSERT` sql-string in R, then use `sqlQuery` to insert the values from my intermediary table to the final table. Afterwards, the intermediary table is dropped from the DB. I have several functions which do this task to other tables in this way, and all of them work perfectly, it's only this one that doesn't want to behave.

I know that the sql-string works, because I can run that exact sql statement in Access directly with the two tables, and there are no issues. However, when I run the query within the context of the function I wrote I get the error `07002 17 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]COUNT field incorrect`. As per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449776/odbc-microsoft-access-drivercount-field-incorrect) and [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/069152d3-bc2d-47fd-bff5-7ed873ff36d6/error-07002-microsoftodbc-sql-server-drivercount-field-incorrect-or-syntax-error?forum=adodotnetdataproviders) from the MS developer forum, I looked to make sure I'm escaping any column names, and that I've referred to the columns correctly, and that data types match from my `data.frame` to the DB table. But, still not working.

### Code:

```
# the devDB argument is the file path to the database on my machine, 
# and is defined in my session environment

insertFunction <- function(df, devDB){
  
  sqlStat <- "INSERT INTO tbl_Source ( ID, [Set], Source, [Source Desc], Type, [Age (d)], [On Product?], Formulation, [AB Program], [Date Rec] )
                SELECT intermediaryTable.ID, intermediaryTable.[Set], intermediaryTable.Source, 
                intermediaryTable.SourceDesc, intermediaryTable.Type, intermediaryTable.Aged, 
                intermediaryTable.OnProduct, intermediaryTable.Formulation, intermediaryTable.ABProgram, intermediaryTable.DateRec
                FROM intermediaryTable;"
  
  res <- tryCatch(
    {
      # establish the connection to whichever DB
      chan <- RODBC::odbcDriverConnect(connection = paste("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=", devDB, sep = ""), case = "nochange")
      
      # if the intermediary table remains from the last update, remove it from the DB
      if(any(grepl("intermediaryTable", RODBC::sqlTables(channel = chan)$TABLE_NAME))){
        RODBC::sqlQuery(chan, query = "DROP TABLE intermediaryTable;")
      }
      
      # save the data.frame as a table in the database
      RODBC::sqlSave(channel = chan, dat = df, tablename = "intermediaryTable", rownames = FALSE)

      # run the sqlStat char string from above to add the records, and save the 
      # output to log the update status in a log file
      dbUpdateStatus <- RODBC::sqlQuery(channel = chan, query = sqlStat)
    },
    error = function(cond){
      return(paste("Error occurred! ", cond, " timestamp:",Sys.time()))
    }
  )
  
  RODBC::sqlQuery(channel = chan, query = "DROP TABLE intermediaryTable;")
  RODBC::odbcClose(channel = chan)
  rm(chan)
  
  return(res)
}
```

### Session Info:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] magrittr_2.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6       fansi_0.4.2      assertthat_0.2.1 utf8_1.1.4       crayon_1.4.1     dplyr_1.0.4     
 [7] R6_2.5.0         odbc_1.3.0       DBI_1.1.1        lifecycle_1.0.0  pillar_1.5.0     rlang_0.4.10    
[13] blob_1.2.1       vctrs_0.3.6      generics_0.1.0   ellipsis_0.3.1   RODBC_1.3-16     tools_3.6.1     
[19] bit64_4.0.5      glue_1.4.2       bit_4.0.4        purrr_0.3.4      hms_1.0.0        compiler_3.6.1  
[25] pkgconfig_2.0.3  tidyselect_1.1.0 tibble_3.1.0
```

The ODBC driver used is Access Database Engine 2010, [available here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

## Reprex

### Table Structure

table name: tbl_Source

- ID: Autonumber (long-int)
- Set: double
- Source: double
- Source Desc: short text
- Type: short text
- Age (d): double
- On Product?: short text
- Formulation: short text
- AB Program: short text
- Date Rec: Date/Time

### Sample Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(12495:12497),
  Set = rep(998, 3),
  Source = c(1:3),
  SourceDesc = c("Desc 1", "Desc 2", "Desc 3"),
  Type = c("Type1", "Type2", "Type3"),
  Aged = c(28, 24, 5),
  OnProduct = c("No", "No", "Yes"),
  Formulation = rep(NA, 3),
  ABProgram = rep(NA, 3),
  DateRec = rep("04/01/2021", 3)
)
```

The sample data `df` shares column names that work with the `insertFunction` code at the top.

Please, let me know if there's anything else anyone else sees is missing for a reprex.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've noted weirdness using RODBC before, and can reproduce the issue using RODBC, but DBI works fine. Since I see your environment contains both DBI and odbc, I highly suggest you use it. If I were to do a guess, I'd guess since RODBC has no separate execute function and something goes wrong there.

Let's translate your code:

```r
library(DBI) 
# I've noted some peculiarities when not attaching DBI, though this code seems to run without it

insertFunction <- function(df, devDB){
  
  sqlStat <- "INSERT INTO tbl_Source ( ID, [Set], Source, [Source Desc], Type, [Age (d)], [On Product?], Formulation, [AB Program], [Date Rec] )
                SELECT intermediaryTable.ID, intermediaryTable.[Set], intermediaryTable.Source, 
                intermediaryTable.SourceDesc, intermediaryTable.Type, intermediaryTable.Aged, 
                intermediaryTable.OnProduct, intermediaryTable.Formulation, intermediaryTable.ABProgram, intermediaryTable.DateRec
                FROM intermediaryTable;"
  
  res <- tryCatch(
    {
      # establish the connection to whichever DB
      chan <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = paste0("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=", devDB))
      
      # We don't need to remove the table when it exists, since we specify `overwrite = T`
      # save the data.frame as a table in the database
      # We need to specify batch_rows = 1 since Access does not support batch inserts through DBI
      DBI::dbWriteTable(chan, df, name = "intermediaryTable", batch_rows = 1, overwrite = T)

      # run the sqlStat char string from above to add the records, and save the 
      # output to log the update status in a log file
      dbUpdateStatus <- DBI::dbExecute(chan, sqlStat) # Note: this won't match RODBCs output
    },
    error = function(cond){
      return(paste("Error occurred! ", cond, " timestamp:",Sys.time()))
    }
  )
  # If the try-catch fails due to a connection problem, the following line will likely fail too, and the database connection won't close
  DBI::dbExecute(chan, "DROP TABLE intermediaryTable;")
  DBI::dbDisconnect(chan)
  rm(chan)
  
  return(res)
}
```

Note that it's generally preferable to append to the target table directly instead of writing to an intermediary and then appending, and DBI can do that with `dbAppendTable`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! In the past I haven't had any issues with RODBC for these types of DB transactions. It literally just started with this one table. I even use the function above with other data.frames and tables, and it works fine. I do use DBI often for my SELECT queries, and then use RODBC because it allows batch inserts. I don't know how large this project will get in the future, and so wanted to keep that functionality. I'll try to implement your suggestion, and then mark as answered or not a little later.

Comment: I tried your suggestion of using `DBI` instead, but still had the same issue. The other part was that using `dbAppendTable()` was also not working. Instead of returning an error message, it just didn't return any output in the console.